# Selecting specific cells

Tags: jquery, contains

```
$('table.listings td:contains("You")').each(function(){
 $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').addClass('highlighted');
});
```

I have multiple `table.listings` on the page but the one that contains "You" is selected and I want to addClass `highlighted` to the 2nd cell in each row, but the above code isn't working as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('table.listings:contains("You") td:nth-child(2)').addClass("highlight");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('table.listings td:contains("You")').each(function(){
    $("td:nth-child(2)", $(this).parent().parent().get(0)).addClass('highlighted');
});
```

Comment: this will do things which sometimes redundant, `$('table.listings td:contains("You")')` , if the same table contains more `<td>`'s with "You" then the codes inside gets executed more for the same table, doing the same thing.

Comment: It's worth noting that the person that's asking the question is doing that too, so it's likely that "You" is only in one part of the table, or he/she doesn't care if it's done multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table.listings :contains("You")').each(function(){
 $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').addClass('highlighted');
});
```